# Display one image of commerce product in product display view

Tags: commerce

I have created a view which display indexed nodes (product displays) in teaser mode.
The commerce product entity has a field called `field_images` which contain several images.

In teaser display mode of the commerce product, I choose to display Images.
On the views, for each commerce product, all images are displayed.
I'd like only the first to be displayed.
Unfortunately, I can't set a delta in the teaser display mode form.
I could have set the delta to 0.

I will seems reasonable to me, but I can't find an easy way to fix it.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Image Delta Formatter module : https://www.drupal.org/project/image_delta_formatter and set the delta to 0 in the product commerce display teaser